# Unable to edit toolbar in a non main activity, the app crashes

Tags: android, android-layout, android-studio

there isn't much to explain, when I try to access the toolbar from another activity, the application crashes.
this is the code I wrote in a child activity of main activity:

```
Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
    String titleName = ("example");
    getSupportActionBar().setTitle(titleName);
```

this is what I wrote in the manifest:

```
<activity
        android:name=".SingleActivity"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar"
        android:parentActivityName=".MainActivity"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait"/>
```

and this is the XML of the activity:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:layoutDirection="ltr">

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/titleId2"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:paddingBottom="2dip"
    android:paddingTop="6dip"
    android:textColor="@color/colorPrimaryDark"
    android:textSize="16sp"
    android:textStyle="bold" />




<TextView
    android:id="@+id/dateId2"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:paddingBottom="2dip"
    android:textColor="@color/colorAccent" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/authorId2"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:paddingBottom="2dip"
    android:textColor="@color/colorAccent"
    />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/contentId2"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textColor="#5d5d5d"
    android:textStyle="bold"
    android:scrollbars = "vertical"
    android:autoLink="web"/></LinearLayout>
```

Do you guys have any idea what could be the problem?
and it also seems like the logcat doesn't obtain any error, and the app first freezes for a second and the crashes.
Thank you!

Comment: How you are accessing toolbar from another activity?

Comment: I am sure there is some issue in your parent one i.e  MainActivity..are you extending MainActivity problematically ? can you paste the onCreate method of SingleActivity here

Answer (score 2):

You can not access the `view` of other actvity

You need to add **`Toolbar`** in your Activity layout

Try this

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layoutDirection="ltr">

    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/titleId2"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:paddingBottom="2dip"
        android:paddingTop="6dip"
        android:textColor="@color/colorPrimaryDark"
        android:textSize="16sp"
        android:textStyle="bold" />




    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/dateId2"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:paddingBottom="2dip"
        android:textColor="@color/colorAccent" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/authorId2"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:paddingBottom="2dip"
        android:textColor="@color/colorAccent"
        />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/contentId2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textColor="#5d5d5d"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:scrollbars = "vertical"
        android:autoLink="web"/></LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

In XML use like this :-

```
      <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
            app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay" />
```

and in java :-

```
ToolBar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);            
toolbar.setTitle("My title");
setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
```

in style.xml :-

```
<style name="AppTheme.PopupOverlay" parent="ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light" />
```